# iOS: space management like `ncdu`

Tags: ios, disk-utility, storage, disk-space

Is there a way to see what files and directories are using the most space on iOS?

iOS itself shows the storage used by each app, but no more finegrained than this. E.g., my video player app has gigabytes of data, I want to see which directories there are consuming the most space.

Comment: Sandboxing will not allow one app to see the files of other apps. Doesn't your video player show this within the app?

Comment: @nohillside Obviously, that app doesn't. I don't know about the sandboxing; can't the app extract the needed data from Files API? Apple is the most anti-competitive of the big tech ...

Comment: The Files API only can be used if the app holding the files provides its content there. If it would, you could just use the Files app directly (actually, did you check?).

Comment: PS: Also not sure why securing apps from malicious access by other apps. is anti-competitive.

Comment: @nohillside Files app does show me the files, but I want an easy to use interface like `ncdu` and not check each directory's size manually. Apple's bad storage management tooling benefits Apple directly as Apple sells both local storage and iCloud, with the local storage being exorbitant. This would be fine if 3rd party apps could be written for this (as they are for other OSes), but Apple locks down the API. The security angle is bullshit, if Apple supported verified builds from opensource repos I could install GPL solutions with complete peace of mind.

Comment: Honestly I don't see how iCloud is relevant for the discussion here. Also, if you want an open platform, iOS (and to a lesser extend also macOS) probably is/are the wrong choice.